# invalid url web browser errors

Tags: vb.net, url

I'm wondering how I can prevent my program giving me a break/continue page when a url is not correct.
[The box I'm trying to not close the program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujK7e.png)

I click my button to get the source of webpage of an invalid url is when I get the unwanted error box like here;

```
Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(capi)
RichTextBoxShorten1.Text = sourceString
```

Where **CAPI** is an invalid url. I'm wondering how I can make the error box not show when given an error, but print/do SOMETHING about not showing the error and cancel the event, other than closing the entire solution.

I am thinking somewhat like this;

*When an error occurs; print the error and cancel the event On click*

Comment: Learn about exceptions and the `Try` block.

Comment: [Try...Catch...Finally reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx)